# Error uninstalling Anaconda - unable to call Python

Tags: python, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda in order to use with some specific packages, but wanted to move back to just Python.

I tried uninstalling Anaconda using:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

Which didn't work, but somehow removed my ability to call Python from the command window (running Mac)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: please add the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: /Users/JosephBlair/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin